# Order an object by it's property values

Tags: javascript

I receive data from a REST API, which contains `id` and `name` properties ordered by `name`. The data is:

```
Array [
  Array [
    960,
    "",
  ],
  Array [
    588,
    "         Computer Associate System, LLC",
  ],
  Array [
    481,
    "1111",
  ],
  Array [
    91,
    "123Inkjets",
  ],
  Array [
    73,
    "1and1 Internet",
  ],
]
```

Then, I want to create an object that still ordered by name:

```
const vendors = {};
const data = response.data.DATA;
if (data !== undefined) {
   for (let index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
      const value = data[index];
      vendors[value[0]] = value[1];
   }
}
```

However, the result of `vendors` is not ordered by the name. How can I order it? I still need to return vendors as an object with `"id" : "name"`

Thanks

Comment: There are existing questions, relevant to this. Including: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Comment: Nope. That question is ordering by key, not value

Comment: Whilst you want to order by value, that is still akin to you ordering the keys based on their value.

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 As I understand it, object properties in JavaScript are not reliably ordered in the way you might want them to be. Arrays, Sets and Maps are ordered data structures, however.

Comment: Objects are not ordered. If order is important to you, keep them as an array.

Comment: Why the object is not keeping the array order? It's coming already ordered from the database (data variable)

Comment: ES2015 guarantees that non-integer keys are ordered in insertion order [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). However, you are making the keys as the ID - those are integer keys. They will be ordered in ascending order automatically. If you need to preserve the order, keep them in an array, just map the inner arrays to objects (this sounds like what you need anyway).

Comment: @Klaycon yes, it is what I need. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 can you show how the `vendors` object will be used?

Comment: @Klaycon I need the vendors object with "id" : "value". It will be used in a react native Picker component